# ActionBarSherlock onClick listener

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-actionbar

I've read already android ActionBar documentation and didin't fount how to set tup a onClick listener to a actiobar menuitem? Here's how i create actionbar button (code from abs samples project). How do I set a listener to each menu item in this list?

```
  public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {           
          menu.add("Save")
          .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_compose_inverse)
          .setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM);

      menu.add("Share")
          .setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM | MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_WITH_TEXT);

      menu.add("Refresh")
          .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_refresh_inverse)
          .setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM | MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_WITH_TEXT);  

       return true;
    }
```

Comment: here is a better answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10849964/how-to-distinguish-two-menu-item-clicks-in-actionbarsherlock

Answer (score 2):

override onOptionsItemSelected() method in your fragment/activity